# How to extract a single value from array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having an one dimensional array named `$cs_subject_id` as follows:

```
Array
(
    [cs_subject_id] => 8
)
```

Now I want `$cs_subject_id` should contain simply a value not an array. Can you tell me how to convert this array to a single value? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `$cs_subject_id = $cs_subject_id["cs_subject_id"]`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
$cs_subject_id = $array['cs_subject_array'];
```

Replace $array with the name of the variable containing your array.

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
$cs_subject_id = $cs_subject_id['cs_subject_id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$id = $cs_subject_id["cs_subject_id"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one value in your array you can use this:

```
$id = current($cs_subject_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [**`extract`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) function which will create a variable called `$(the key of the array value)` which is `$cs_subject_id` in this case:

```
$array = array('cs_subject_id' => 8);

extract($array);

var_dump($cs_subject_id); // returns int(8)
```

But better use this when you have more than one elements in the array. If you have only one element then you can simply assign its value to a variable:

```
$cs_subject_id = $array['cs_subject_id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's version of an [IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)

```
$cs_subject_id = call_user_func(function() use ($array) { return $array['cs_subject_id']; }, $array);
```